# Cocoapod with vendored_framework unable to link to it's dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a pod that encapsulates multiple frameworks.
ex) MyPod (vendored_frameworks: SNAPSDK, IVA)
IVA has files that require SNAPSDK but
when I try to deploy MyPod I get an error saying files in IVA is not able to recognize SNAPSDK framework

```
#import <SnapSDK/SnapSDK.h> #fail
```

I have access to all frameworks

seems like vendored frameworks(IVA) is unable to find another vendored framework (SNAPSDK)

Inside IVA project's Framework Search Paths, I have added

```
$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers
$(PODS_ROOT)/MyPod(the enclosing one that i am making cocoapod of)/MyPod/
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/IVA
```

[

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MyPod'
  s.version          = '0.35.0'


  s.description      = <<-DESC
IVA
    DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://www.google.com'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'kevinkang88' => 'kevinkang88@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => '', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.header_dir = './'

  s.ios.source_files = ['MyPod/Classes/**/*', 'MyPod/SnapSDK.framework/Headers/*','MyPod/sdkprivate.framework/Headers/*']
  s.ios.public_header_files = [..]

   s.resource_bundles = {
     'MyPod' => ['...']
   }
   s.resource = '...'

   s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MyPod/SnapLiveness.framework', 'MyPod/SnapSDK.framework', 'MyPod/MobileFlow.framework', 'MyPod/private.framework'


  s.frameworks = 'Foundation', 'UIKit'
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -ObjC'
  }
end
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue??? I also need an answer